# here-doc couldn't parse backtick

Tags: bash, here-document

Why does this works

```
bold="$(tput bold)"
reset="$(tput sgr0)"
c0="${reset}${bold}"
cat <<EOF
${c0} \`
EOF
```

but not this one?

```
bold="$(tput bold)"
reset="$(tput sgr0)"
c0="${reset}${bold}"
cat <<EOF
${c0} `
EOF
```

Comment: because backticks are expanded in here-documents (just like variables), if the delimiter (`EOF`) is not quoted. `\`...\`` is just another syntax for `$(...)` (command substitution).

Comment: Thanks! Need read more docs.